# How to execute Command which is in a variable

Tags: shell-script

My Condition is like below.

```
SEARCH="find `pwd` -name"

bash> $SEARCH resources.xml | grep $SEARCH_DIR | grep $1 | grep ‘cells’
```

But am not getting the `pwd` as referenced in that variable.

Comment: `SEARCH="find $(pwd) -name"`

Comment: @Serge that would define the variable with the _current_ value of `pwd`, not the value at the point of execution

Comment: Verify the value of `$SEARCH` by echoing it using `echo "$SEARCH"`. And what is the value of `$SEARCH_DIR`?

Comment: @roaima the question is unclear then

Comment: Were you actually using `”`, or was it a regular `"`?

Comment: @serge & @roaima 
When i use this command  SEARCH="find $(pwd) -name", then it is coming like this
" find /tmp/ -name " , 
but my requirement is am using the variable SEARCH dynamically so need to come like this 
"find `pwd` -name" etc.

Also if we use a command inside a variable,  when the Variable called eg $SEARCH the command(pwd) is executed already. like "find /tmp -name" ..
but requirement it should not execute before that..

Comment: I believe I have already addressed this requirement in [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288648/100397)

Answer (score 3):

```
alias SEARCH='find . -name'
```

Or

```
SEARCH() { find . -name "$1"; }
```

Usage

```
SEARCH resources.xml | ...
```

Note that `SEARCH` is not a variable. You could define the command as a variable (`SEARCH='find . -name'`) but the alias or function definition is more usual practice.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that the current directory is `/original/directory` at the time the `SEARCH=…` line is evaluated and `/later/directory` at the time the `$SEARCH …` line is evaluated.

The command substitution `` `pwd` `` is evaluated at the time the variable `SEARCH` is defined, so `SEARCH` is set to `find /original/directory -name`. If the current directory at that time doesn't contain any whitespace or wildcard characters, then `$SEARCH resources.xml` later calls `find` in that directory, i.e. `find /original/directory -name resources.xml`.

If the original current directory contains whitespace or wildcards, this won't work. Stuffing a command into a variable like this doesn't work except in very simple cases. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

If you wanted to run `find` in `/later/directory`, then you could just run `find .`. But a variable isn't the right tool here. A variable is for storing a string. A command with parameters is not a string, it's a *list* of strings. And a shell code snippet can be stored in a string, but `$SEARCH` does *not* run the value of `SEARCH` as a shell code snippet (once again, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)). To store a shell code snippet for later use, define a function.

```
SEARCH () {
  find "$PWD" -name "$@"
}
…
SEARCH resources.xml | …
```

Once again, this runs `find` in `/later/directory`. If you wanted to run `find` in `/original/directory`, the best way is to store that directory in a variable and use that variable later.

```
original_directory="$PWD"
SEARCH () {
  find "$original_directory" -name "$@"
}
…
SEARCH resources.xml | …
```